# Set Fragment's controller in XML

Tags: xml, sapui5

When I instantiate a fragment via my controller as a second parameter it takes a controller like so:

```
var myFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("fragment", controller);
this.getView().byId("place").addContent(myFragment);
```

Seems like I can't achieve the same thing when I am creating it in the XML directly.

```
<core:Fragment fragmentName="myFragment..."  type="XML" />
```

I tried to add `controller="myController"` and `controllerName="myController"` Then I check the documentation and I saw that there is no such a property. It gets instantiated with the controller of the view I call it from. Do I miss something is there any way to achieve this in the XML.

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2355. In short: won't be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI5 fragments are like light weight reusable UI parts. Unlike Views, fragments do not have a predefined associated controller assigned to them. They will use the controller of the View in which they are instantiated. For this reason you could have a single fragment used in many different Views each using their respective View's controller.

So when you use it in a View in XML, it will use the View's controller automatically without explicitly specifying it.

You can read more here: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/234320f8d8ee45b39c60893116d60351

Answer (score 3):

Another option - you can implement a reusable fragment with its *own* controller by adding it directly to the Component.js file. I'll show an example from a recent project of mine (edited slightly for privacy)

First, create your fragment view:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" >
<Dialog
    id="orderTypeDialog"
    title="{i18n>orderTypeSelect}"
    draggable="true"
    icon="sap-icon://sales-order"
    beforeOpen="beforeOpen"
    busy="{= ${async>/DocumentTypesSet}.length > 0}"
    >
    <content>
        <VBox>
        <RadioButtonGroup
            class="sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd"
            id="orderTypeGroup"
            select="radioButtonSelect"
            buttons="{/DocumentTypesSet}">
            <RadioButton
                text="{Description}"
                useEntireWidth="true"
                selected="{= ${DocumentType} === ${order>/DocumentType}}"
                />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
        </VBox>
    </content>
    <endButton>
        <Button text="{i18n>confirm}" press="confirmOrderType"/>
    </endButton>
</Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Then, define your fragment's controller within a class definition:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/base/ManagedObject"
], function (ManagedObject) {
"use strict";
return ManagedObject.extend("soe.controls.OrderTypeDialog", {
    constructor: function(oView){
        this._oView = oView;
    },
    exit:function(){
        delete this._oView;
    },
    open : function () {
        var oView = this._oView;
        var oDialog = oView.byId("orderTypeDialog");
        var oController = oView.getController();
        var oOrderModel = oView.getModel("order");
        if(!oDialog){
            var oFragmentController = {
                beforeOpen:function(oEvent){

                },
                onCloseDialog: function(){
                    oOrderModel.setProperty("/DocumentType", "");
                    oOrderModel.setProperty("/OrderTypeDescription", "Order");
                    oDialog.close();
                    oOrderModel.refresh();
                },
                confirmOrderType: function(oEvent){
                    oDialog.close();
                    if(oEvent.getSource().data("route")){
                        oController.goTo(oEvent);
                    }
                },
                radioButtonSelect: function(oEvent){
                    var index = oEvent.getParameter("selectedIndex");
                    var oSelectedButton = oEvent.getSource().getButtons()[index];
                    var oContext = oSelectedButton.getBindingContext();
                    var sPath = oContext.getPath();
                    var sType = oContext.getProperty(sPath+"/DocumentType");
                    var sDescription = oContext.getProperty(sPath+"/Description");
                    oOrderModel.setProperty("/DocumentType", sType);
                    oOrderModel.setProperty("/OrderTypeDescription", sDescription);
                }
            };
            oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "soe.view.fragments.OrderTypeDialog", oFragmentController);
            oView.addDependent(oDialog);
        }           
        // open dialog
            oDialog.open();
        }
    });
});
```

Finally, in your Component's `init` method, you need to instantiate it with this (don't forget to import OrderTypeDialog.js in your Component's `sap.ui.define` statement):

```
this.orderTypeDialog = new OrderTypeDialog(this.getRootControl());
```

In the above, `this` refers to the Component. In the OrderTypeDialog class you need to pass the component's root control (`this.getRootControl()`) so you can add the dialog as a dependent.

Whenever you need to open the dialog, you can do so from any controller in your app by calling:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().orderTypeDialog.open();
```